# Kmeans algorithm for k=2 which gives equal cluster size outputs

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, spherical-kmeans

I am using a modified Lloyd's algorithm for obtaining equal cluster size outputs in kmeans with k=2.
Following is the pseudocode:

```
- Randomly choose 2 points as initialization for the 2 clusters (denoted as c1, c2)
- Repeat below steps until convergence
    - Sort all points xi according to ascending values of ||xi-c1|| - ||xi-c2||, i.e. differences in distances to the first and the second cluster
    - Put top 50% points in cluster 1 , others in cluster 2
    - Recalculate centroids as average of the allocated points (as usual in Lloyd's)
```

Now the above algorithm is working fine for me empirically:

1. It gives balanced clusters
2. It always decreases the objective

Has such an algorithm been proposed or analyzed before in literature? Can I get some references please?

Answer (score 2):

A more general version for more than 2 clusters is explained here:

https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/same-size_k_means

I have seen k-means with various size constraints several times in literature, but I don't have any references at hand. I'm not convinced of this: forcing clusters to have the same size contradicts the k-means idea of finding the least-squares best approximation IMHO, as it means deliberately choosing a worse approximation.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

In my opinion, there is a crucial difference between my algorithm and the one in the reference: For k=2, the point assignment step can be solved exactly as above, while for the more general k>2 it does not seem to be the case. Hence, in the above link, they are using a local point swapping procedure which is unnecessary when k=2.

I wanted to know if proof for the case of k=2 exists somewhere..

Comment: I don't think the k=2 case is of much special interest; because one usually is looking for more clusters. I definitely have seen this kind of operation for k=2 in metrical indexing.